# Zoomdata - Failed to validate connection

Tags: java, spring, bigdata

```
2016-06-28 08:15:39,542 WARN  [c.z.c.s.i.ConnectionsService] Failed to validate connection 'Brokerage12'
com.zoomdata.model.service.ValidationException: Failed to establish connection
        at com.zoomdata.solr.SolrStorageFactory.validateConnection(SolrStorageFactory.java:66) ~[connector-solr-2.2.7.jar!/:na]
        at com.zoomdata.core.service.impl.ConnectionsService.validate(ConnectionsService.java:196) ~[core-2.2.7.jar!/:na]
        at com.zoomdata.core.service.impl.ConnectionsService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eacd836a.invoke(<generated>) [core-2.2.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:718) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:654) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at com.zoomdata.core.service.impl.ConnectionsService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5ab8947f.validate(<generated>) [core-2.2.7.jar!/:na]
        at com.zoomdata.web.controller.ConnectionsController.validateConnection(ConnectionsController.java:151) [zoomdata-web.jar!/:na]
        at com.zoomdata.web.controller.ConnectionsController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4166c0dd.invoke(<generated>) [zoomdata-web.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:718) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:654) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at com.zoomdata.web.controller.ConnectionsController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9667ce92.validateConnection(<generated>) [zoomdata-web.jar!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor256.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224) [websocket-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
        at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:104) [metrics-servlet-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
```

Comment: I am trying to connect to solr data source and getting above error

Comment: You didn't mention what connection string you have used. The information provided by you is not enough

Answer (score -1):

how to install zoomdata in centos.
I tried as per per steps in zoomdata docs, but it promts dat zoomdata have installed but couldn't get user interface dashboard.

Comment: Kindly write another question than asking as an answer